# How to set specific seed for random number generator in expl3 for use with xfp

Tags: expl3, latex3, random-numbers, xfp

I am using the `xfp` package to generate some random numbers, and am trying to figure out how to specify a specific random seed for the pseudo random number generator (so it gives the same results whenever compiled with a given seed).

Here is a minimal code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
% TODO: set specific random seed here

\begin{document}
A random integer between 0 and 10: $\fpeval{randint(0,10)}$
\end{document}
```

I know that `xfp` is an interface to `expl3`, in which one can set a random seed using `\sys_gset_rand_seed:n`. However, I don't know how to do so in my document. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn\sys_gset_rand_seed:n{100}\ExplSyntaxOff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the `expl3` programming environment:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {42}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Use an integer between 0 and 2<sup>28</sup> − 1.

If you need to set the seed several times, you can define an interface:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setrandomseed \sys_gset_rand_seed:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and then use `\setrandomseed{42}` at the appropriate spot.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!